# splitting an array with single key and string value into an array with multiple keys and values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

**I have a table which stores the courses registered by students during a semester and session. I populated it with course-codes for a particular student. Here is the function that fetches the course-code below:**

```
function get_course_code(){
    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT course_code ";
    $query .= "FROM tbl_registered_courses_400 ";
    $query .= "WHERE matric_no = '03/55ec101' LIMIT 10";

    $course_code_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    confirm_query($course_code_set);
    return $course_code_set;
}
```

**When I called the function in my main page. It returned the following result**

```
$courseCode = get_course_code();
$courseFilter = '';
while ($courseList = mysql_fetch_array($courseCode)){
    $courseList['course_code']; 
    $courseFilter .= "\""."{$courseList['course_code']}"."\",";
    $courseFilter;
}

$course = array($courseFilter);

print_r($course);
```

`Array ( [0] => "PHY 432","CSC 491","CHM 401","CHM 402","MAT 451","MAT 452","CSC 423","BLY 401", )`

**I want to split the $course array into an array that will have the values of the string in the above to read**

```
array(
    [0] => PHY 432
    [1] => CSC 491
    [2] => CHM 401
    [3] => CHM 402
    .
    .
    .
    e.t.c
)
```

**The string data in the $course array is from the course_code column in the database.
My intention is to use the results of the new array to form a row in the database that will hold the results of each matric_no for different courses done for the semester/session. I would appreciate any help I can get to get this done.**

Comment: as a side note, you should switch from `mysql` to `mysqli` or `PDO` as it is becoming depreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create the array and then assign the values to that array.

```
$courseCode = get_course_code();
$course = array();
while ($courseList = mysql_fetch_array($courseCode)){
    $course[] = $courseList['course_code'];
}

print_r($course);
```

Comment: Whao...Thanks a million. I would want you to be my mentor. Wouldn't know if I can use this medium to communicate you personally?

Comment: I answer here on my small spare time and, believe me, you will find very good and helping people here :). Glad I helped.

Comment: Then I would be a regular visitor to StackOverFlow. Once again...Thanks a bunch!